# APC opcode caching on different file versions

Tags: php, caching, apc, opcode

We have a single server with several **DIFFERENT** versions of the **SAME** web application deployed on it.

For instance :

- `www.myserver.com`
- `rc.myserver.com`
- `alpha.myserver.com`

We fear that there might be collisions between versions of the same PHP Class. Do APC correctly handle this? If not, how to workaround this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC caches based on the *path* to the class, not just the class name. So as long as each of your versions have their own copy of the class you shouldn't have any problems.