# How does APC optcode cache identify a class?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I'm running a one instance Apache setup with multiple virtual hosts that runs different versions of the same code base.

By this I mean that one virtual host can server one version of a class and another can server second version of the same class (same namespace, same name).

```
/file/path/host-a/MyClass.php
/file/path/host-b/MyClass.php
```

Sometimes I get an exception that shows me that one of the virtual hosts uses the "wrong" version of a class. E.g. on host b I get an exception with file path to script of `/file/path/host-a/MyClass.php`

I thought that the APC optcode cache used the file path, at least as a part of the key, but I'm fearing, that it only uses a qualified class name like:

```
My\Namespace\MyClass
```

Is that the case? Please point to any documentation on this subject if possible.

Comment: [APC opcode caching on different file versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549493/apc-opcode-caching-on-different-file-versions)

Comment: Thanks hakra -- post it as an answer then I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Well this does not answer why you have got an issue. It looks like - as you have a path here that differs - the problem you face should never happen. But it does happen, right?

Comment: Also that is not the APC documentation, just a link. It's not that authorative I'd say.

Comment: It does happen yes - but you with your answer I don't have to waste time on looking into a possible APC problem. Now I can focus my search on the class loader. Thanks

Comment: Let's leave the question unanswered until you find "your bug" (if any). we can then make the existing answer more prominent.

Comment: @hakra, I've identified my problem to be related to class loading (uses memcached and there was a problem with the ways keys were generated).

Comment: In your own code? If so, please leave an answer. Also if you can create some kind of "lessons learned" out of the error you stumbled over would be cool. E.g. how debugging is possible / easier, what did clash with your hashing and why just the kind of information that could be useful for other programmers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15885/discussion-between-michael-and-hakra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Though is was unable to find any documentation on the answer to this question [php - APC opcode caching on different file versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549493/apc-opcode-caching-on-different-file-versions) explains that the APC optcode cache in fact does use the path of the file that defines the class to distinguis classes with the same name.

## Debugging

After @hakra pointed out to me the behaviour of APC, I was able focus my efforts on the **class loader**. My class loader uses `memcached` as cache for storing the class paths. It turned out that the code for building cache keys were the cause of the problem - and not the APC which it seemed to be.

So should you be in a similar situation where your see that the incorrect "versions" of a class is loaded ensure that you class loader is working as expected. One obvious clue is of course the file path of the problem class.